# Active tab wont deactivate when another is linked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using bootstrap 3.0 and have done a link to tab number 4 called "Installer Resources" on the bottom of tab number 1 called "Overview." The link is "apply."

However you will not the page does not scroll nor does the 4th tab "Installer Resources" become active even though the content of tab 4 does show after the link is clicked.

I would say that I have a special javascript for this, but it's just bootstrap 3.0.0

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thank you. :)

[link](https://www.tep.com/renewable/home/pv/)

Comment: cab you create fiddle please.

Comment: Fiddle? I don't understand.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net OR http://www.bootply.com/new